# Generate input fields based on a input and store it properly

Tags: python, django

I have a field called subjects that asks users how many subjects do they have and based on the number they input I want to generate the input fields of same number. And How and where do I store those inputs.

MODELS.PY

```
#this field will determine how many input fields to generate
subjects = models.IntegerField()
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def generate_forms(request):
    no_of_fields = request.GET.get('subjects')
    if no_of_fields:
        #generate other inupts
        #save it in the database
```

Besides generating the input, how do I save those data in the database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using postgresql i suggest create a json column based on your subject input save each value as key value.. example  if your number of subjects is 3 and you save something like this--> {'subject':1,'subject2':4,'subject3':3} or create a array column which saved as list.. like [1,2,3]..

Answer (score 1):

If you use postgres you can use django postgres specefic models fields(Like ArrayField).[django specefic fields documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

For another  databases you can create model for your subjects and for each subject you can insert new data in Subject model.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    other_filed = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)

def generate_forms(request):
    other_field = 1
    subjects = request.GET.get('subjects')
    if subjects and subjects != '':
        for subject in subjects:
            Subject.objects.create(desc=subject, other_field=other_field)
```